# Why record is not saved until i click on the row in NSTableView?

Tags: objective-c, macos, nstableview

I have created trivial app in OSX that uses core data. I used binding so I didn't write any code. However, I notice that if I don't click on the row in NSTableView after the insert, and I quit the app, record is not saved. If I do click on the row, record is saved. Anyone can tell me why is that?

I have checked all the properties on the NSTableView, but I couldn't figure out why this is happening. Any help will be deeply appreciated.

Regards, John

Comment: maybe the codes for saving is binded on table click event?

Comment: no it is not. normal binding, that is all